# how to Avoid HTML [object HTMLOptionElement]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to collect all the option from one select element  and insert them dynamically to another select element.

```html
    <select name="" id="main-products-images-standards-select">
        <option value="1">Name 1</option>
        <option value="2">Name 2</option>
        <option value="3">Name 3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="" id=""></select>
```

```js
var  main_products_images_standards_select = document.getElementById('main-products-images-standards-select').options 
var standards = '';
   for(var i = 0 ; i < main_products_images_standards_select.length ; i++)
    {
            standards += main_products_images_standards_select[i];
    }
```

when I print each option in the loop I get the required results, but as I collect them together I'm ending up with the next results

```js
[object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement]
```

What should I do to avoid those results
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.value` to get the value of `option`

```js
var main_products = document.getElementById('main-products')
var standards = '';
for (var i = 0; i < main_products.length; i++) {
  standards += main_products[i].value;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = standards;
}
```

```html
<select name="borderStyle" id="main-products">
  <option value="solid">solid</option>
  <option value="dotted">dotted</option>
  <option value="dashed">dashed</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

### Update

If you want to reprint the `select` with same options then use `outerHTML` on the `id`

> You can use loop to run or have select number of times you have option or how many times you want

```js
var main_products = document.getElementById('main-products')
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = main_products.outerHTML;
```

```html
<select name="borderStyle" id="main-products">
  <option value="solid">solid</option>
  <option value="dotted">dotted</option>
  <option value="dashed">dashed</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Rana Thanks for your answer .  I need the all element not just the value

Comment: @YuvalSh updated the answer see if it solves your issue

Comment: Thanks great answer

Comment: Welcome, happy to help @YuvalSh . If you fund this helpful you can upvote it and if this answer solved your problem, than you can mark it as accepted solution